# How to make a table with a variable number of columns?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to insert a rather complex table in Latex. The problem is that the table actually consists of different tables in one. I am trying to create something like this (the difference in line weight is not important):
[image]

I manage to create each table separately using \multirow and \multicolumn. 
This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.5ex}

....

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Descriptieve statistieken van de leerling- en schoolkenmerken}
\label{lsk_descr}
\begin{tabular} {l c c c c c c c c c}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} \\
    \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10} 
     & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX & & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX \\
    \hline
    X1 & 10,0405 & 0,4987 & 8,17 & 13,50 & & 10,1208 & 0,6365 & 8,42 & 14,17 \\
    X2 & 2,0011 & 1,0672 & 0,00 & 4,00 & & 1,9776 & 1,1012 & 0,00 & 4,00 \\
    X3 & . & . & . & . & & 4,7423 & 1,8267 & 0,00 & 7,00 \\
    X4 & 0,1443 & 0,1512 & 0,00 & 0,87 & & 0,2124 & 0,2014 & 0,00 & 0,94 \\
    GEM\_X1 & 1,9955 & 0,3579 & 0,56 & 2,85 & & 1,9463 & 0,4395 & 0,36 & 3,40 \\
    GEM\_X2 & 0,0924 & 0,1356 & 0,00 & 0,80 & & 0,1333 & 0,3013 & 0,00 & 1,45 \\
    GEM\_X3 & . & . & . & . & & 4,7199 & 0,8183 & 1,63 & 6,69 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular} {l c c c c}
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & GEM & SD & MAX & MIN \\
    Leeftijd & 10,0834 & 0,5778 & 8,1667 & 14,1700 \\
    Aantal & 1,9894 & 1,0842 & 0,0000 & 4,0000 \\
    GEM\_Y1 & 0,1782 & 0,1812 & 0,0000 & 0,9355 \\
    GEM\_Y2 & 1,9710 & 0,4013 & 0,3636 & 3,4000 \\
    GEM\_Y3 & 0,1128 & 0,2342 & 0,0000 & 1,4545 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular} {l c c c c c c c c}
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
    & N & \% & & N & \% & & N & \% \\
    Geslacht & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Jongen & 2227 & 48,38 & & 2161 & 48,38 & & 4388 & 48,88 \\
    \quad Meisje & 2283 & 50,62 & & 2306 & 51,62 & & 4589 & 51,12 \\
    Thuistaal & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Test & 3870 & 85,81 & 3594 & 80,46 & & 7464 & 8315 \\
    \quad Anders & 640 & 14,19 & 873 & 19,54 & & 1513 & 16,85 \\
    Migratie & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Autochtoon & 4098 & 90,86 & & 3901 & 87,33 & & 7999 & 89,11 \\
    \quad G1 & 256 & 5,68 & & 388 & 8,69 & & 644 & 7,17 \\
    \quad G2 & 156 & 3,46 & & 178 & 3,98 & & 334 & 3,72 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This gives me the following result in latex:
[image]

I still see two problems:

1. the two tables are placed next to each other instead of underneath each other
2. I would like to set the tables at textwidth, I tried \resizebox{\textwidth} but then I get the three tables next to each other.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use several `\begin{tabular}`...`\end{tabular}` in one `\begin{table}`...`\end{table}` to do that.

Comment: Regarding problem #1, tabular acts like an inline box.  So you can just use \\ to go to the next line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use three distinct `tabular*` environments wrapped in an overall `tabular`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs,array,siunitx}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.5ex}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\footnotesize

\caption{Descriptieve statistieken van de leerling- en schoolkenmerken}
\label{lsk_descr}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  w{l}{6em}
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
}
Variabele & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1999} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9} 
& {GEM} & {SD} & {MIN} & {MAX} & {GEM} & {SD} & {MIN} & {MAX} \\
\midrule
X1      & 10,0405 & 0,4987 & 8,17 & 13,50 & 10,1208 & 0,6365 & 8,42 & 14,17 \\
X2      &  2,0011 & 1,0672 & 0,00 &  4,00 &  1,9776 & 1,1012 & 0,00 &  4,00 \\
X3      & {.}     & {.}    & {.}  & {.}   &  4,7423 & 1,8267 & 0,00 &  7,00 \\
X4      &  0,1443 & 0,1512 & 0,00 &  0,87 &  0,2124 & 0,2014 & 0,00 &  0,94 \\
GEM\_X1 &  1,9955 & 0,3579 & 0,56 &  2,85 &  1,9463 & 0,4395 & 0,36 &  3,40 \\
GEM\_X2 &  0,0924 & 0,1356 & 0,00 &  0,80 &  0,1333 & 0,3013 & 0,00 &  1,45 \\
GEM\_X3 & {.}     & {.}    & {.}  & {.}   &  4,7199 & 0,8183 & 1,63 &  6,69 \\
\end{tabular*}
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  w{l}{6em}
  S[table-format=2.4]
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
}
Variabele & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Totaal} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& {GEM} & {SD} & {MAX} & {MIN} \\
\midrule
Leeftijd & 10,0834 & 0,5778 & 8,1667 & 14,1700 \\
Aantal   &  1,9894 & 1,0842 & 0,0000 &  4,0000 \\
GEM\_Y1  &  0,1782 & 0,1812 & 0,0000 &  0,9355 \\
GEM\_Y2  &  1,9710 & 0,4013 & 0,3636 &  3,4000 \\
GEM\_Y3  &  0,1128 & 0,2342 & 0,0000 &  1,4545 \\
\end{tabular*}
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  w{l}{6em}
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
}
Variabele & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1999} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Totaal} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
& {N} & {\%} & {N} & {\%} & {N} & {\%} \\
Geslacht \\
\quad Jongen     & 2227 & 48,38 & 2161 & 48,38 & 4388 & 48,88 \\
\quad Meisje     & 2283 & 50,62 & 2306 & 51,62 & 4589 & 51,12 \\
Thuistaal \\
\quad Test       & 3870 & 85,81 & 3594 & 80,46 & 7464 & 83,15 \\
\quad Anders     &  640 & 14,19 &  873 & 19,54 & 1513 & 16,85 \\
Migratie \\
\quad Autochtoon & 4098 & 90,86 & 3901 & 87,33 & 7999 & 89,11 \\
\quad G1         &  256 &  5,68 &  388 &  8,69 &  644 &  7,17 \\
\quad G2         &  156 &  3,46 &  178 &  3,98 &  334 &  3,72 \\
\end{tabular*}
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This might be a start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering\sffamily
    \caption{The Table Caption}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Part 1 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{} l @{\quad} *{4}{C} >{\hspace{1cm}}c *{4}{C}@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{.15\linewidth}{\bfseries Variabele}& 
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries 1999} && 
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries 2015}\\\cmidrule(r){2-5}\cmidrule(l){7-10}
        & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX && GEM & SD & MIN & MAX \\\midrule
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        X1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4   && 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        \multicolumn{10}{c}{\dots} %<-- Add data!
    \end{tabularx}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Part 2 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{} l @{\quad} *{4}{C}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{.15\linewidth}{\bfseries Variabele}& 
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Totaal}\\\cmidrule{2-5}
        & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX \\\midrule
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        Leeftijd & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\dots} %<-- Add data!
    \end{tabularx}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Part 3 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{} l @{\quad} *{2}{C} >{\hspace{1cm}}c *{2}{C}@{} >{\hspace{1cm}}c *{2}{C}@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{.15\linewidth}{\bfseries Variabele} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 1999} && 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 2015} && 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Totaal}\\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(l){8-9}
        & N & \% && N & \% && N & \% \\\midrule
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        Geslacht &&&&&&&&\\
        \quad Jongen & 1 & 2 && 3 & 4 && 5 & 6\\
        \multicolumn{9}{c}{\dots}\\ %<-- Add data
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It leads to:
[image: Table]

**But:** I had problems with the `\cmidrule`-Command and the space between the columns.(Adding `@{<space>}` in to the table-setup didn't work properly). Right now I just an additional column. (You have to keep it in mind while adding the data!).

Anyway: On this site are many many intelligent people, who might have an idea to solve it in a more elegant way!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), you may typeset your three tabular as one. Use either `minipage` and [capt-of](https://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of), a `table`-environment or a document class from the [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle to make `caption` and `label` that is not separated from the tabular body. The tabulars are set `\footnotesize`, if not the tabulars are too wide to fit inside the margins.

In addition, I have fine tuned the columnwidths to avoid `bad hbox` warnings. Also, I added some `\hbox{<wd>` some places to line up the columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.75ex}

\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\begin{table}[htp]% not h on its own
\caption{Descriptieve statistieken van de leerlingen schoolkenmerken}
\label{lsk_descr}
\footnotesize
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *19)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *13)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *12)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *11)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *11)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *11)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *13)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *12)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *11)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/120 *12)\relax}
            }

\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Border switch (on of)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

% R1 Heading
\thead{
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil 1999}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil 2015}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R2
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lrb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Variabele}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil GEM}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil SD}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil MIN}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil MAX}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil GEM}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil SD}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil MIN}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{\vfil MAX}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
}
% R3
\brow
    \bb\setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{X1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignR\cell{10,0405}
    \alignR\cell{0,4987}
    \alignR\cell{8,17}
    \alignR\cell{13,50}
    \alignR\cell{}
    \alignR\cell{10,1208}
    \alignR\cell{0,6365}
    \alignR\cell{8,42}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{14,17}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R4
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{X2}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignR\cell{2,0011}
    \alignR\cell{1,0672}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \alignR\cell{4,00}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{1,9776}
    \alignR\cell{1,1012}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{4,00}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R5
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{X3}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{4,7423}
    \alignR\cell{1,8267}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{7,00}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R6
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{X4}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignR\cell{0,1443}
    \alignR\cell{0,1512}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \alignR\cell{0,87}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{0,2124}
    \alignR\cell{0,2014}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{0,94}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R7
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{GEM\_X1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignR\cell{1,9955}
    \alignR\cell{0,3579}
    \alignR\cell{0,56}
    \alignR\cell{2,85}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{1,9463}
    \alignR\cell{0,4395}
    \alignR\cell{0,36}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{3,40}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R8
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{GEM\_X2}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignR\cell{0,0924}
    \alignR\cell{0,1356}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \alignR\cell{0,80}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{0,1333}
    \alignR\cell{0,3013}
    \alignR\cell{0,00}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{1,45}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% R9
\brow
    \bb\setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{GEM\_X2}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{4,7199}
    \alignR\cell{0,8183}
    \alignR\cell{1,63}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{6,688}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T2R1 Heading
\thead{
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Totaale}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T2R2
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lrb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Variabele}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\hspace{4em}GEM}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\hspace{2em}SD}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\hspace{5em}MIN}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{\hspace{2em}GEM}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
}
% T2R3
\brow
    \bb\setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{Leeftijd}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{10,0834}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,5778}
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{8,1667}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{14,1700}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T2R4
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{Aantal}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{1,9804}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{1,0842}
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,0000}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{4,000}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T2R5
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{GEM\_Y1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,1782}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,1812}
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,0000}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,9355}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T2R6
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{GEM\_Y1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{1,9710}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,4013}
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,3636}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{3,4000}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T2R7
\brow
    \bb\setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{GEM\_Y3}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,1128}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,2342}
    \cell{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{0,0000}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{1,4545}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R1 Heading
\thead{
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil 1999}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil 2015}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Totaale}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R2
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lrb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Variabele}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil N}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\%}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil N}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\%}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil N}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\%}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
}
% T3R3
\brow
    \bb\setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{Geslacht}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R4
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}Jongen}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{2227}
    \cell{49,38}
    \cell{}
    \cell{2161}
    \cell{48,38}
    \cell{}
    \cell{4388}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{48,88}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R5
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}Meisje}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{2283}
    \cell{50,62}
    \cell{}
    \cell{2306}
    \cell{51,62}
    \cell{}
    \cell{4589}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{51,12}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R6
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{Thuistaal}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R7
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}Test}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{3870}
    \cell{85,81}
    \cell{}
    \cell{3594}
    \cell{80,64}
    \cell{}
    \cell{7464}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{83,15}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R8
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}Anders}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{640}
    \cell{14,19}
    \cell{}
    \cell{873}
    \cell{19,54}
    \cell{}
    \cell{1513}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{16,85}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T39
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{Migratiea}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R10
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}Autochtoon}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{4098}
    \cell{90,86}
    \cell{}
    \cell{3901}
    \cell{87,33}
    \cell{}
    \cell{7999}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{89,11}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R11
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}G1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{256}
    \cell{5,68}
    \cell{}
    \cell{388}
    \cell{8,69}
    \cell{}
    \cell{644}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{7,17}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
% T3R12
\brow
    \bb\setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignL\cell{\hspace{0.5em}22}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{156}
    \cell{3,46}
    \cell{}
    \cell{178}
    \cell{3,98}
    \cell{}
    \cell{334}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{3,72}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow

\makeatother

\end{calstable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]