# Fixed font size for table with variable columns

Tags: tables, fontsize

I am constructing a table consisting of three different `\tabular` environments. Each environment consists of a different amount of columns. I want the three tables to be all at textwidth so I used `\resizebox{\textwidth}` but now I get the following table:
[image]

I would like all cells to have the same font size. I tried `\normalsize` but it gives the same result as in the picture.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.5ex}
...
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Descriptieve statistieken van de leerling- en schoolkenmerken}
\label{lsk_descr}
\normalsize
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular} {l c c c c c c c c c}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} \\
    \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10} 
     & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX & & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX \\
    \hline
    X1 & 10,0405 & 0,4987 & 8,17 & 13,50 & & 10,1208 & 0,6365 & 8,42 & 14,17 \\
    X2 & 2,0011 & 1,0672 & 0,00 & 4,00 & & 1,9776 & 1,1012 & 0,00 & 4,00 \\
    X3 & . & . & . & . & & 4,7423 & 1,8267 & 0,00 & 7,00 \\
    X4 & 0,1443 & 0,1512 & 0,00 & 0,87 & & 0,2124 & 0,2014 & 0,00 & 0,94 \\
    GEM\_X1 & 1,9955 & 0,3579 & 0,56 & 2,85 & & 1,9463 & 0,4395 & 0,36 & 3,40 \\
    GEM\_X2 & 0,0924 & 0,1356 & 0,00 & 0,80 & & 0,1333 & 0,3013 & 0,00 & 1,45 \\
    GEM\_X3 & . & . & . & . & & 4,7199 & 0,8183 & 1,63 & 6,69 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular} {l c c c c}
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & GEM & SD & MAX & MIN \\
    \hline
    Leeftijd & 10,0834 & 0,5778 & 8,1667 & 14,1700 \\
    Aantal & 1,9894 & 1,0842 & 0,0000 & 4,0000 \\
    GEM\_Y1 & 0,1782 & 0,1812 & 0,0000 & 0,9355 \\
    GEM\_Y2 & 1,9710 & 0,4013 & 0,3636 & 3,4000 \\
    GEM\_Y3 & 0,1128 & 0,2342 & 0,0000 & 1,4545 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular} {l c c c c c c c c}
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
    & N & \% & & N & \% & & N & \% \\
    \hline
    Geslacht & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Jongen & 2227 & 48,38 & & 2161 & 48,38 & & 4388 & 48,88 \\
    \quad Meisje & 2283 & 50,62 & & 2306 & 51,62 & & 4589 & 51,12 \\
    Thuistaal & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Test & 3870 & 85,81 & & 3594 & 80,46 & & 7464 & 8315 \\
    \quad Anders & 640 & 14,19 & & 873 & 19,54 & & 1513 & 16,85 \\
    Migratie & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Autochtoon & 4098 & 90,86 & & 3901 & 87,33 & & 7999 & 89,11 \\
    \quad G1 & 256 & 5,68 & & 388 & 8,69 & & 644 & 7,17 \\
    \quad G2 & 156 & 3,46 & & 178 & 3,98 & & 334 & 3,72 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Never use ` \resizebox` for tables! As you can see it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: please don't use `\resizebox` for anything with text in and especially not tables, your image shows why:-)

Comment: when posting examples please don't do `...` add `\begin{document}`  etc so that people can run it without error to see the problem and test answers.

Comment: If you look at your previous posting, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493273/9632, I have set up your tabular within the text width and with consistent fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this layout, based on `tabularx` and `siunitx`, for an alignment of the numbers on the decimal comma.

It does not make sense to stretch the second table to the text width. However, you might have this table on the same row as the first with a landscape layout.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.5ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Descriptieve statistieken van de leerling- en schoolkenmerken}
\label{lsk_descr}
\sisetup{copy-decimal-marker, }
\normalsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}X *{2}{S[table-format=2.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{=}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1999} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
     & {GEM} & {SD} & {MIN} & {MAX} &{GEM} & {SD} & {MIN} & {MAX} \\
    \midrule
    X1 & 10,0405 & 0,4987 & 8,17 & 13,50 & 10,1208 & 0,6365 & 8,42 & 14,17 \\
    X2 & 2,0011 & 1,0672 & 0,00 & 4,00 & 1,9776 & 1,1012 & 0,00 & 4,00 \\
    X3 & {.} & {.} & {.} & {.} & 4,7423 & 1,8267 & 0,00 & 7,00 \\
    X4 & 0,1443 & 0,1512 & 0,00 & 0,87 & 0,2124 & 0,2014 & 0,00 & 0,94 \\
    GEM\_X1 & 1,9955 & 0,3579 & 0,56 & 2,85 & 1,9463 & 0,4395 & 0,36 & 3,40 \\
    GEM\_X2 & 0,0924 & 0,1356 & 0,00 & 0,80 & 0,1333 & 0,3013 & 0,00 & 1,45 \\
    GEM\_X3 & {.} & {.} & {.} & {.} & 4,7199 & 0,8183 & 1,63 & 6,69 \\
    \bottomrule
\\
\end{tabularx}

{\mbox{}\hfill\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular} {l S[table-format=2.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=2.4]}
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
    & {GEM} & {SD} & {MAX} & {MIN} \\
    \midrule
    Leeftijd & 10,0834 & 0,5778 & 8,1667 & 14,1700 \\
    Aantal & 1,9894 & 1,0842 & 0,0000 & 4,0000 \\
    GEM\_Y1 & 0,1782 & 0,1812 & 0,0000 & 0,9355 \\
    GEM\_Y2 & 1,9710 & 0,4013 & 0,3636 & 3,4000 \\
    GEM\_Y3 & 0,1128 & 0,2342 & 0,0000 & 1,4545 \\
    \bottomrule \\
\end{tabular}\hfill}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {X*{2}{S[table-format=4]S[table-format=2.2]c}S[table-format=4]S[table-format=2.2]}
    \multirow{2}{1cm}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{8-9}
    & {N} & {\%} & & {N} & {\%} & & {N} &{ \%} \\
    \midrule
    Geslacht & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Jongen & 2227 & 48,38 & & 2161 & 48,38 & & 4388 & 48,88 \\
    \quad Meisje & 2283 & 50,62 & & 2306 & 51,62 & & 4589 & 51,12 \\
    Thuistaal & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Test & 3870 & 85,81 & & 3594 & 80,46 & & 7464 & 83.15 \\
    \quad Anders & 640 & 14,19 & & 873 & 19,54 & & 1513 & 16,85 \\
    Migratie & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Autochtoon & 4098 & 90,86 & & 3901 & 87,33 & & 7999 & 89,11 \\
    \quad G1 & 256 & 5,68 & & 388 & 8,69 & & 644 & 7,17 \\
    \quad G2 & 156 & 3,46 & & 178 & 3,98 & & 334 & 3,72 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.5ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]% not h on its own
\caption{Descriptieve statistieken van de leerling- en schoolkenmerken}
\label{lsk_descr}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}% reduce inter-column space to make wide table fit
\centering

\bigskip

% not needed, tables are always this size \normalsize
% no!!!!\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% if you did have this you would need a % here
\begin{tabular} {@{}l c c c c c c c c c@{}}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2015} \\
    \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10} 
     & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX & & GEM & SD & MIN & MAX \\
    \hline
    X1 & 10,0405 & 0,4987 & 8,17 & 13,50 & & 10,1208 & 0,6365 & 8,42 & 14,17 \\
    X2 & 2,0011 & 1,0672 & 0,00 & 4,00 & & 1,9776 & 1,1012 & 0,00 & 4,00 \\
    X3 & . & . & . & . & & 4,7423 & 1,8267 & 0,00 & 7,00 \\
    X4 & 0,1443 & 0,1512 & 0,00 & 0,87 & & 0,2124 & 0,2014 & 0,00 & 0,94 \\
    GEM\_X1 & 1,9955 & 0,3579 & 0,56 & 2,85 & & 1,9463 & 0,4395 & 0,36 & 3,40 \\
    GEM\_X2 & 0,0924 & 0,1356 & 0,00 & 0,80 & & 0,1333 & 0,3013 & 0,00 & 1,45 \\
    GEM\_X3 & . & . & . & . & & 4,7199 & 0,8183 & 1,63 & 6,69 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular} {@{}l c c c c@{}}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & GEM & SD & MAX & MIN \\
    \hline
    Leeftijd & 10,0834 & 0,5778 & 8,1667 & 14,1700 \\
    Aantal & 1,9894 & 1,0842 & 0,0000 & 4,0000 \\
    GEM\_Y1 & 0,1782 & 0,1812 & 0,0000 & 0,9355 \\
    GEM\_Y2 & 1,9710 & 0,4013 & 0,3636 & 3,4000 \\
    GEM\_Y3 & 0,1128 & 0,2342 & 0,0000 & 1,4545 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular} {@{}l c c c c c c c c@{}}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Variabele} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1999} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Totaal} \\
    \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
    & N & \% & & N & \% & & N & \% \\
    \hline
    Geslacht & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Jongen & 2227 & 48,38 & & 2161 & 48,38 & & 4388 & 48,88 \\
    \quad Meisje & 2283 & 50,62 & & 2306 & 51,62 & & 4589 & 51,12 \\
    Thuistaal & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Test & 3870 & 85,81 & & 3594 & 80,46 & & 7464 & 8315 \\
    \quad Anders & 640 & 14,19 & & 873 & 19,54 & & 1513 & 16,85 \\
    Migratie & & & & & & & & \\
    \quad Autochtoon & 4098 & 90,86 & & 3901 & 87,33 & & 7999 & 89,11 \\
    \quad G1 & 256 & 5,68 & & 388 & 8,69 & & 644 & 7,17 \\
    \quad G2 & 156 & 3,46 & & 178 & 3,98 & & 334 & 3,72 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493273/9632) to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493219/9632). If you set up your tabular correctly, your will find a solution on both your questions.

[image]