# Fixed font size for tables with variable columns

Tags: tables, fontsize, width

I have a problem that similar the [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493257/fixed-font-size-for-table-with-variable-columns) one.

Basically I need different tables be with a same text font, align to the center (don't have a problem that the width of the tables be different).
My case is different from the one that mentioned early by constraint that my tables are not in the same page, and have text between them, so it's not practically to put it in one table object, is their any solution?

Additional question that solving that issue similar way is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493219/how-to-make-a-table-with-a-variable-number-of-columns).

Comment: never use `\resizebox` on tables. Latex will use the font size that you specify which is normalsize by default or use `\small` or `\footnotesize`. You are only getting inconsistent font  sizes as you are explicitly requesting that the text be scaled by arbitrary amounts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you man!